# Bottom floating div inside a container (like in Facebook messages) - Take 2

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, css-float

I need to have a floating div inside a container. When I move the scroll bars it should move accordingly INSIDE a specified container div. I found something similar here: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/mashable-floating-effect-example-with-jquery/ except in my case it needs to be floated inside another div/container AND it should stick to the bottom of the page. So for example, when I scroll from bottom to top the floated div should not move up until the bottom of the browser window "touches" it, Then it should start moving until I reach the top of the container div's top.

I found another example here: [Spotlight: Constrained Stickies with jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/spotlight-constrained-stickies-with-jquer/)
but this also starts the floater at the TOP of the containing element. not sure how to modify it.

Here is what i have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/CCpJg/25/

thanks

Here is the solutions by William Niu: (link below)

Html:

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="header"><h1>header</h1></div>

    <div id="body">
        <h1>content top -> when scrolling up the box should STOP here (at the line right above this text)</h1>

        <div id="floating-box"></div>
        <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; ">content bottom -> when scrolling down the box should STOP here (at the line right below this text)</span>

    </div>
    <div id="footer"><h1>footer</h1></div>
    <div id="debug"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#floating-box{
    width:90px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color:#BBBBBB;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index:1;
}

#page{
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#header{
    border:1px solid blue;
    height:1010px;
    margin:8px;
}
#body{
    border:1px solid blue;
    height:540px;
    margin:8px;
    position: relative;
}
#footer{
    border:1px solid blue;
    height:1500px;
    margin:8px;
}
h1,h2{
    padding:16px;
}

#debug {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    color: red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();

var $box = $('#floating-box');
var $parent = $('#body');
var parentAbsoluteTop = $parent.offset().top;
var parentAbsoluteBottom = parentAbsoluteTop + $parent.height();
var topStop = parentAbsoluteTop + $box.height();

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    var windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + windowHeight;

    if (windowBottom < topStop)
        $box.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '0px',
            bottom: 'auto'
        });
    else if (windowBottom >= topStop && windowBottom <= parentAbsoluteBottom)
        $box.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 'auto',
            bottom: '0px'
        });
    else
        $box.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 'auto',
            bottom: '0px'
        });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this demo modified from the one you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/CCpJg/32/

**EDIT:**
http://jsfiddle.net/CCpJg/40/

Comment: almost there. The only problem is that it should STOP at the top of the "content" div when scrolling up AND it should move down to the bottom of "content" div when scrolling down. thanks

Comment: Ok, not there yet. I've updated content to see it better visually. http://jsfiddle.net/CCpJg/35/. Plus, the floating box when moving should alwasy "stick" to the bottom when scrolling up/down.

Comment: I think the 2nd link is probably what you're after.